# Qt for Android - undefined reference to ANativeWindow_fromSurface

Tags: android, c++, qt, gstreamer-1.0

I am a beginner of Qt,
I was trying to use Qt to make an Android application and used GStreamer(not QtGStreamer) to stream video through RTSP.
But when I used

```
QPlatformNativeInterface *nativeInterface = QApplication::platformNativeInterface();
jobject activity = (jobject)nativeInterface->nativeResourceForIntegration("QtActivity");
QAndroidJniEnvironment * qjniEnv;
JNIEnv * jniEnv;
JavaVM * jvm = qjniEnv->javaVM();
jvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&qjniEnv), JNI_VERSION_1_6);
jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&jniEnv,NULL);

jint r_id_content = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/R$id", "content");

QAndroidJniObject view = ((QAndroidJniObject) activity).callObjectMethod("findViewById", "(I)Landroid/view/View;", r_id_content);
if (view.isValid()) {
    QAndroidJniObject child1 = view.callObjectMethod("getChildAt", "(I)Landroid/view/View;", 0);
    QAndroidJniObject child2 = child1.callObjectMethod("getChildAt", "(I)Landroid/view/View;", 0);
    if (child2.isValid()) {
        QAndroidJniObject sHolder = child2.callObjectMethod("getHolder","()Landroid/view/SurfaceHolder;");
        if (sHolder.isValid()) {
            QAndroidJniObject theSurface = sHolder.callObjectMethod("getSurface","()Landroid/view/Surface;");
            if (theSurface.isValid()) {
                ANativeWindow* awindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(jniEnv, theSurface.object());
                qDebug() << "This is a ANativeWindow " << awindow;
            }
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Views are not loaded yet or you are not in the Qt UI Thread";
    }
}
```

to get the ANativeWindow,
It got an error: `undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_fromSurface'`

I have added `QT += androidextras` in .pro and
`#include<android/native_window.h>`
`#include<android/native_window_jni.h>`
in .cpp file, I don't know what else should I do.

Is there anyone can help me to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I added `LIBS += -landroid` in *.pro file. So, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I use QtAndroid::androidActivity() and callMethod, callObjectMethod.

I add :

```
android {
```

QT       += core_private gui_private androidextras

DEFINES += Q_OS_ANDROID \
            HAVE_TIME_H \
            HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H \
            HAVE_LRAND48 \
            HAVE_NETINET_IN_H
}

to .pro file So, it works.